# Menu getActive() method returns parent menu id

Tags: menu, menu-item, joomla-1.5, menu-parameters

I have menu item that has "section type" and child menu item item with "article type". I didn't want to have pagination in child menu item, so set param show_pagination to 0. Unexpectedly pagination is still enabled. I was debugging params and explored that Joomla! method `JSite::getMenu()->getActive()` loads parent menu id, not child! It also loads parent params. I can't get rid of that.

Comment: Also `$_GET` parameter `Itemid` returns parent menu id

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Problem was caused by JoomSEF component. Alias had wrong Itemid...

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the system stops bumping it as unresolved.